# Running All Unit Test Resharper 9 and VS 2013

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I am trying to run all unit tests in a certain folder. When I click on that folder and select "Run All Tests" Resharper opens a window showing all my tests but all the tests have a "?" next to it which says "Pending Unknown. Derived Unknown".

If I click on single test and then say "Run Test" then it works fine.

Comment: Can you verify that your project is building properly?